# protect certain phrases for search

Tags: lucene, elasticsearch

I am currently trying to improve the corner cases of my elasticsearch-results. One particular is giving me a headache: "google+" which is simply reduced to "google". Omitting special chars is usually fine but for this one I would want an exception. Any ideas how to achieve this?

I tried the following setup:

```
{
  "index": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "default": {
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "synonym",
            "word_delimiter"
          ]
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "synonym": {
          "type": "synonym",
          "synonyms_path": "analysis/synonym.txt"
        },
        "word_delimiter": {
          "type": "word_delimiter",
          "protected_words_path": "analysis/protected.txt"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

protected.txt contains one line with google+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the [Standard tokenizer](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/index-modules/analysis/standard-tokenizer.html) is stripping out the `+` from `google+`. You can check it using the [analyze api](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/admin-indices-analyze.html). I'd use the [Whitespace tokenizer](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/index-modules/analysis/whitespace-tokenizer.html) instead and properly configure the [Word delimiter token filter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/index-modules/analysis/word-delimiter-tokenfilter.html) that you're already using.

Answer (score 0):

I think pattern replace would be a better idea - http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/index-modules/analysis/pattern_replace-tokenfilter.html